# Personal file sharing error, can't find webdav package

Tags: 11.04, mac, file-sharing

I want to share files from my ubuntu laptop to my mac pro (mac os x), my question is, what do I have to install to be able to use this program?

I tried to install "WebDAV" but I couldn't find it. (`sudo apt-get install webDAV`)
I looked in the help section for more info but nothing there helped me.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Opening any APT GUI (Synaptic, Ubuntu Software Centre etc) and searching All Software for webDAV will show a list of results which includes Personal File Sharing and will look something like this

[image: picone]

Selecting Personal File Sharing click on the "More Info" button which will show the add ons available which are shown like so

[image: pictwo]

You need to install these packages:

- [apache2.2-bin](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/natty/+package/apache2.2-bin)
- [libapache2-mod-dnssd](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libapache2-mod-dnssd)

### Through the Terminal (Command Line)

```
sudo apt-get install apache2.2-bin
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-dnssd
```

Comment: apache2.2-bin is a 404, how am I suppose to install these packages?

Comment: @Tom: Fixed the link to apache2.2-bin.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to share files using samba..

First you need to install samba, to do this open a terminal window (press Alt+F2 and type: gnome-terminal) and copy+paste the following line:

```
sudo apt-get install samba samba-common system-config-samba
```

After installing samba you need to go to the location of the folder you want to share or you can make a new folder. To make a new folder click with your right mouse button and select Create Folder and name your folder.

Now start the Samba Server Configuration (press Alt+F2 and type: gksu system-config-samba) enter your password and click on the OK button. To add a folder you want to share click on the + button followed by clicking on the Browse button. Select the folder you want to share and click on the OK button. Enter a description for your shared folder. Mark the check boxes if you want the folder to be writable or visible. Click on the Access tab and give access to the user(s) you want, when finished click on the OK button. Now the shared folder is added to your Samba Server Configuration.

Now go to the folder you want to share, select the folder and click on it with your right mouse button and select Sharing Options. Add a comment and change the permissions for others to create and delete files and for the guest access rules. When done click on the Create Share button. Now you will be asked if you want nautilus to add some permissions automatically… click on the Add the permissions automatically button.

After this step you are finished and your shared folder will be visible and accessable from another computer in your network using Windows or Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Is there any way I can install this without using the terminal? Just wondering how a new user would be expected to do this :)

Comment: ok, did sudo apt-get install samba samba-common system-config-samba
and that dialog looks exactly the same. Any ideas?

Comment: Here is a step by step guide with screen shots of every step, i wrote this for sharing folders on Ubuntu 10.10. I also use it for sharing folders on Ubuntu 11.04. [link](http://www.n00bsonubuntu.net/content/install-samba-and-share-folders-ubuntu-10-10-maverick-meerkat/).

Answer (score 0):

There's a typo in your install command (double b), but it should be:

```
sudo apt-get install davfs2
```

Comment: didn't work... .

Comment: what didn't work? the command? i hope you didn't try to execute `apt-get` on your mac?

Comment: haha, none of the command made a difference! :( it didn't help.)

Comment: my mac has file sharing built in my laptop hasn't