# Enable Personal File Sharing

Tags: sharing, file-sharing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Personal file sharing error, can't find webdav package](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38130/personal-file-sharing-error-cant-find-webdav-package)

Hi,

I'm trying to enable Personal File Sharing, but Ubuntu is telling me I need some additional packages. It's not told me which packages I need or where I can install them.

[image: helpful error message]

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://askubuntu.com/q/38130/10698 .