# why doesn't my ftp transfer work?

Tags: 11.10, windows, ftp

I am working on ubuntu 11.10 
i need to transfer some files to my windows 7 system on the LAN.
while connecting with ftp get an error i.e ftp: connection : connection refused

```
ftp 192.168.0.72
ftp: connection: connection refused
ftp>
```

but i can ping the windoes system

```
ping 192.168.0.72
5 packets transmitted , 5 packets received 0% packet loss
```

but i can ftp from windows to ubuntu

plz provide any solution

Comment: just go to your network folder and click the windows computers icon. Log in and place the files where u want them... I do it all the time...

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/q/38130/10698 this works for windows too, at least for me...

Comment: I think you need to provide a port on the computer that you are connecting to, What port is assigned on the windows machine? add that to your ftp address.

Comment: Just so you know, 11.10 is no longer supported. This site only handles questions with supported Ubuntu versions, this question might be closed as a result to that.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you have an FTP server running on your Windows system?  It seems to either not be present, not running, or not configured to allow a connection in from the error you are relaying.

Either way, the problem you are describing (if you are truly attempting to FTP into that Windows box) is more an FTP server setup / Windows security (firewall) / or possibly networking question more than an Ubuntu issue.

An alternative solution, as @Alvar suggested in the comments, would be to share a folder across the network, providing R/W access (with security configurations as you please) and then simply save documents there.  That would be a much simpler method, and would remove the need for running an FTP server of any kind (which seems like it would be overkill on a LAN).